# Installing spdlog by copying contents of include directory

Tags: c++, cmake, spdlog

I'm trying to use spdlog as a logging library, but I do not want to use my package manager (apt) to install it. I have copied the spdlog directory under include to the root of my project directory, but when I try to compile I get include errors because the `#include` directives in the spdlog headers are all absolute (relative to the project root), instead of relative, gcc cannot find the files.

```
0:10: fatal error: spdlog/common.h: No such file or directory
 #include "spdlog/common.h"
```

Short of changing all the includes in the spdlog library to relative, how can I use spdlog in my project? I'm also using CMake to compile my project; I have a `build` directory in my project root and from within it I call `cmake ..` and then `make` to compile; is there something I need to add to my CMakeLists.txt file to include spdlog?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake can not find include files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449949/cmake-can-not-find-include-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the project root directory into the cmake include_directories, like this:

```
include_directories(
    /absolute/path/
)
```

Or in the project root directory, edit CMakeLists.txt and add this:

```
include_directories(
    .
)
```

Comment: It was a matter of including the current directory in the search path. It seems obvious because the current directory is the one that contains `spdlog/` so then obviously the `spdlog/<whatever>.h` can be resolved. Thanks.